# Duplicate control error is a field but is used like a type

Tags: c#

I want to dynamically duplicate a "Panel" with all controls inside...

but it gives me an error and I can't run the application...

```
Panel1 MyPn = new Panel1();
```

the error is:
Panel1 is a field but is used like a type

Comment: By the way, are we talking ASP.NET?

Comment: What is Panel1 a control you created with the control added to it or a panel on a form?

Comment: no its no ASP.NET.....Panel1 is a Panel control and contains controls

Comment: You may want Panel myPn = new Panel1();, but with the information you have here it hard to tell. Maybe show us how your creating Panel1?

Comment: @N4TKD That won't work -- Panel1 is a field, you cannot instantiate it.

Comment: @nphx I see the error says that but I am not sure what Panel1 is, or should be anyway.

Comment: @N4TKD `Panel Panel1;` so Panel1 is a variable.

Comment: @nphx It is more likely he is calling this outside a method, but we really don't have the information to tell for sure.

Comment: PANEL1 is a Panel Control but I added a Panel to the form and I added controls to the panel1 and I want to duplicate this panel1 with controls inside

Comment: I made a button and the button click will duplicate the panel1 and adding it to flowlayout

Comment: @DaveMas think in terms of making a UserControl Class and adding the Panel to it, then you can make as many instances of that UserControl class as you need and add them to the forms you need on.

Comment: @N4TKD thanks all for the help...I don't want to create the panel dynamicaly because it has many controls and if I will do what you said I will have a long code to create the panel and 6 controls inside the panel... if it is possible help me please if it is not ... well I have to create all the controls dynamicaly .... thanks

Comment: if I clone the panel ... does it work as the duplicated???

Comment: @DaveMas you don't have to create it dynamically just as a separate UserControl which can be dropped on to the form and instance separately.

Answer (score 0):

Panel1 is an instance of a class, not a type. You need to create a new instance of a Panel and then copy the controls.